# Stretch marks from training

Tags: training

I am 22  1.75 m and 85 kg.
I started training about four months ago, starting with bodyweight exercises and one time I tried to do a full 'flag'. After this I showered and I saw stretch marks on my armpits. I moved to training in a gym and these marks only got bigger and longer. Now I have marks on both sides, looks like a bold red line. They are starting to move to the chest area in one direction and to the biceps in second direction.

I read that they will go away but they have only worsened.
I can live with them in my armpits because no one sees them, but if they move to my chest and biceps I'll look like a mutant.
Is there a way for me to stop them from spreading, other then by stopping my training?

I should mention that in that time frame, I was dieting, and I managed to lose about 4 kg amd gain them back.

Comment: It's completely normal, lots of people get them(including me). If you want to help them fade/prevent them you should buy some moisturiser.

Comment: How much weight did you gain?

Comment: Stretch marks come from rapid growth to where the skin can not accommodate the growth (Skin is fairly elastic). You won't get stretch marks from "that one time you tried doing X". If you are getting lots of lines spreading rapidly, either you are growing very fast, or something else is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Stretch marks are caused by a rapid stretch in the skin. This can be caused by gaining a lot of weight (either muscle or fat). It's very normal for people who attend the gym very often to get them. I have got them too.

Most people will have stretch marks where the skin stretches the most. This will most likely be under the armpits, as you mentioned. I have not heard of people with stretch marks on their biceps or chest. You'll probably not become a mutant after all.

Stretch marks can be 'cured' with some creme you could buy at a drug store.

Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about them. You are probably quite conscious of them at the moment and it's rubbish to feel like that at 22. However, aside from you, people generally won't notice/care.

The good thing is since you're relatively young your skin will adapt to the stretch. Assuming you're not training for body building competitions you will most likely plateau in terms of your general look and weight which should help things.

The best thing you can do is to remain consistent with training (or not training), the yo-yoing won't help stretch marks.

Answer (score 2):

Well as other answers have mentioned, stretch marks are due to skin being not that elastic. Skin elasticity differs from person to person and area to area. I consider them to be medals of bodybuilding and strength training, but still it gets me worried because I don't want too many of them.Newely formed stretch marks are red in color and lightes up after some time, but still one can tell them. I found that applying castor oil on the stretch marks and the area that are prone to get streatch marks can help. I am saying this from my own personal experience and didn't did lot of research, although if you will search online you will find people suggesting the same. You can try cold pressed castor oil, which is highly viscous and better than normally process castor oil. Besides being good for stretch marks, castor oil can be used for treatment of acne, insect & mosquito bites, dandruff, and fungal or yeast infection, i.e any external skin problem. Good luck.